# Can we use driver.findelements inside a pom class?

Tags: java, selenium

```
public class MyPageextends SuperClass 
{
    @FindBy (xpath = "//span[contains(text(),'My Page')]")
    private WebElement myPageLnk;

    @FindBy (id="balanceAmt")
    private WebElement balanceAmtBfrDeduction;

    List<WebElement> chkboxList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate what are you trying to do and what is the problem.

Comment: What is the output when you use driver.findElements? looks like you used and what happened then?

Comment: I am getting Null Pointer exception

Comment: I am trying to retrieve all the check boxs present in the webpage